# jQuery add unique identifier to inputs and class on clone()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This code dynamically adds a unique number to the `id` of each item. I want to be able to add a unique identifier to certain `classes` and `id's` in every new `clone()` and not only to the `.item` itself.

In this snippet I need the function to follow the same pattern for the `[data-input="checkbox0"]` and the `[class="radio0"]`.

As a bonus, I would like to have only one `.add` button `clone()` the new `.items` instead of having one inside of each `.item`.

```js
var rowNum = 0;
$("body").on("click", ".add", function() {
  rowNum++;
  var $item = $(this).parents('.item');
  var next = $item.clone();
  next.attr('id', 'item' + rowNum);
  $item.after(next);
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" id="item0">
  <label class="icon">
<input data-input="checkbox0" class="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
</label>
  <label>
<input type="radio" class="radio0">
<div class="add">
<button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want something like this.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".addbtn", function() {
  var $item = $('.item').last();
  var next = $item.clone();

  // Gets last number dynamically, instead of saving it as global variable.
  var rowNum = parseInt($item.attr("id").substr(4)) + 1;
  next.attr('id', 'item' + rowNum).find("input[type='checkbox']").attr("data-input", "checkbox" + rowNum);
  next.find("input[type='radio']").attr("class", "radio" + rowNum);
  $item.after(next);
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="item" id="item0">
  <label class="icon">
  <input data-input="checkbox0" class="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio0" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just change the html a little bit, move add button outside and use `$('.item').last()` to get last item for the list item

```js
var rowNum = 0;
$("body").on("click", ".addbtn", function() {
  rowNum++;
  var $item = $('.item').last();
  var next = $item.clone();
  next.attr('id', 'item' + rowNum);
  $item.after(next);
  next.find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('data-input', 'checkbox' + rowNum);
  next.find('input[type="radio"]').attr('data-input', 'radio' + rowNum);
  
});
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="item" id="item0">
  <label class="icon">
  <input data-input="checkbox0" class="toggle" type="checkbox" name="toggle"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio0" />
</div>

<button type="button" class="addbtn">Add</button>
```

Comment: That works for moving the add button, thanks. Are you able to help with the first part? dynamically adding the `rowNum` for each the `[data-input="checkbox0"]` and `[class="radio0"]` for each `clone()`?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill: Sorry, I missed this part. I already updated my answer

Comment: Thanks Tan. I have another version where I used append().html() instead of clone() in order to create an item using a dummy variable. The problem is the `.item` is nested inside of the dummy wrapper. Are you able to take a look and see how I can manage this? https://codepen.io/moofawsaw/pen/aGMpye

Comment: @KyleUnderhill: You can take a look on https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzExbv